# How to size a VisualForce component to use the available width within containing pageBlock

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm a little bit stuck getting a custom VisualForce component sized.

I've tried setting the width every way I can think of, but have seen no change. Here is the page code and component code.

I don't think the controllers are relevant.

The general idea is for the page to display the appropriate number of the component which allows the user to select from a number of drop downs and enter some input, and I would like each row of the pageBlock table to take up all available width.

```
<apex:page controller="xController">

<apex:form id="xForm">

    <apex:pageBlock id="objSelectBlock" title="example title">
        <apex:selectList value="{!objName}" required="true" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!objectSelect}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="xBlock" action="{!changeFilterObject}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:pageBlock> 

    <apex:pageBlock title="the {!objLabel} block..." id="xBlock">
        <apex:repeat value="{!filter.criteria}" var="block" id="theRepeat">
            <c:vfCriteriaBlock block="{!block}" id="theValue"/>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

And the component:

```
<apex:component selfclosing="true" html-width="100%">

<apex:attribute name="block" description="This is the block"

    type="CriteriaBlock" required="true"/>

<apex:pageBlockSection id="blockInfo" html-width="100%">

    <apex:pageBlockTable id="rulesTable" columns="4" value="{!block.criteria}" var="row" width="100%">

    <apex:column width="10%"><img border="0" class="icon deleteIcon" src="{!$Resource.delete_icon}" alt="HTML tutorial" width="15" height="15"></img>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Field" width="30%">
        <apex:selectList value="{!row.xfield}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!row.FieldList}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="ops" />
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Relation" width="30%">
    <apex:selectList id="ops" value="{!row.operator}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!row.OperandTypes}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Filter Value" width="30%">
        <apex:inputText value="{!row.filterValue}" /> 
    </apex:column>


  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Here's what the xBlock looks like:
[image: xBlock screenshot]
As you can see, it does not take up the full width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrapping the table in a `<apex:pageblocksection>`

Either set

> columns="1"

like this

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="blockInfo" html-width="100%" columns="1">
```

or change the `<apex:pageblocksection>` to a `<apex:pageblock>`

Comment: You are my hero.

Comment: @LucidLunatic happy I could help :)